# float field value displaying as 0.0 always in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to spring boot and I created a form using thymeleaf. There I have a float value field and that is always displaying 0.0 like a placeholder. I don't want to display a value for that. How can I solve this issue?

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${product}" method="post">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
                <td>Product Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="name" th:field="*{name}"/></td>
                <td class="error" th:errors="*{name}"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brand:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{brand}"/></td>
                <td class="error" th:errors="*{brand}"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Made In:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{madein}"/></td>
                <td class="error" th:errors="*{madein}"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{price}" th:placeholder="price"/></td>
                <td class="error" th:errors="*{price}"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button type="submit">Save</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

Here last field price having the issue.

[click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDlF5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a capital F `Float` for your property rather than a `float`.  It has 2 states:

1. A null default won't display anything in the form fields.
2. After the form has been submitted, the field will have the correct value (and will display as a number).